# How to use Excel ADDRESS funtion inside COUNT function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need to get count of data in many excel sheets and display all in separate sheet.

I know I can get count using

`=COUNT(Sheet2!A1:A10)`

but the problem is number of rows in sheet2 change every day. So need a way to add last cell id of data in sheet2 instead of A10.

I have found a way to get cell id of last data as follows

`=ADDRESS(MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!A:A),COLUMN(Sheet2!A1))`

But I was failed to apply =address(....) output as a input to =count(....)

I tried this

`=COUNT(Sheet2!A1:ADDRESS(MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!A:A),COLUMN(Sheet2!A1)))`

but failed. any way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler just to use the whole column, e.g.

`=COUNT(Sheet2!A:A)`

but if you want to explicity use the range down to the last number then you can use `INDEX/MATCH`, i.e.

`=COUNT(Sheet2!A1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!A:A)))`